# image flip via CSS not working in all browsers

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

i m flipping an image through CSS and its wirking in mozila.but in all other browsers its not working.i m unable to know what i m missing here.

Here is my code for image:

```
<div id="f1_container">
<div id="f1_card" class="shadow">
  <div class="front face">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"/>
  </div>
  <div class="back face center">
    <p>This is nice for exposing more information about an image.</p>
    <p>Any content can go here.</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

and Here is my CSS:

```
#f1_container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 450px;
  height: 281px;
  z-index: 1;
}
#f1_container {
  perspective: 1000;
}
#f1_card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 1.0s linear;
}
#f1_container:hover #f1_card {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  box-shadow: -5px 5px 5px #aaa;
}
.face {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.face.back {
  display: block;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #aaa;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Do you mean IE 6-9 when you say `all browsers`?

Comment: no i mean IE 6-8. i make it work on safari and chrome but its not working in IE 6-8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using bleeding edge CSS properties.

`transform`, for example, only works unprefixed in IE 10, Firefox and Opera.

You can get support in webkit based browsers by duplicating the property with a `-webkit-` prefix (since the implementation is still considered experimental in that engine).

See also: [can I use](http://caniuse.com/#search=transform)

Comment: IE9 supports it with the `-ms-` prefix. 6-8 requires filters or JS.

Comment: yes i m using IE8 nd its not supporting it. is there any way to do this or to achieve what i want to do

Comment: i make it work in safari and chrome but its still not working inIE 6-8